# np.where to compare whether two columns are identical is inconsistent with results from Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to use np.where to compare whether the values from two columns are equal, but I am getting inconsistent results.

```
df['compare'] = np.where(df['a'] == df['b'], '0', '1')
```

Output:

```
a       b               compare
1B      NaN             1
NaN     NaN             1
NaN     NaN             1
32X     NaN             1
NaN     NaN             1
NaN     NaN             1
NaN     NaN             1
NaN     NaN             1
NaN     NaN             1
NaN     NaN             1
NaN     321             1
NaN     Z51             1
NaN     3Y              1
```

It seemed strange that the command would return pairs of NaN as non-matches. I confirmed that column 'a' and column 'b' are both string data types.

I double checked the original CSV files. Using the 'if' formula in Excel, I found several additional pairs of non-matches. The NaN matches were not identified in matches in Excel.

Any tips on troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: Are you 100% sure they are string values? it seems odd. could you add the result of this print? `print(type(df['a'][1]), type(df['b'][1]))`

Comment: Confirmed both are strings. ```<class 'str'> <class 'str'>```

Comment: Could you add your full code - or if it's too long a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`nan`** is a special value which is **not** equal to itself and should **not** be used in equality test. You need to fill the `df` with comparable values beforehand:

```
df_ = df.fillna(0)
df['compare'] = np.where(df_['a'] == df_['b'], '0', '1')
```

---

```
      a    b compare
0    1B  NaN       1
1   NaN  NaN       0
2   NaN  NaN       0
3   32X  NaN       1
4   NaN  NaN       0
5   NaN  NaN       0
6   NaN  NaN       0
7   NaN  NaN       0
8   NaN  NaN       0
9   NaN  NaN       0
10  NaN  321       1
11  NaN  Z51       1
12  NaN   3Y       1
```